# Getting the layout rotation degree for pre-rotated ImageView

Tags: android, animation, rotation, imageview

I use the code below to rotate an ImageView :

```
    public void rotateMenuItemImage(ImageView img, Integer rotationDegree, Integer duration) {
            Integer currentDegree = ????
            RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(currentDegree, currentDegree + rotationDegree, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotate.setDuration(duration);
            rotate.setFillAfter(true);
            img.startAnimation(rotate);
        }
```

I want to add rotation to the current rotated position.
Is there any way to get the amount of rotation of an ImageView?

I know that I can use one variable for any ImageView that contains the last rotation, but as I use this method for many different items, is there any better solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the rotation local to your own app or global ? I mean , do you want the image to be rotated in every other gallery app as well ?

Comment: it is local and it is temporary, it is an arrow-to-left on a button, clicking on it will rotate it to down, and clicking again will rotate it back to the left (initial position)

Comment: You'll need to create your own db and maintain it, if you want that info to persist.

Comment: thanks, but now I've decided to use setContentDescription() and getContentDescription() to maintain the position each time the rotation has been called.

Comment: you wont be able to maintain that state between different instances though. If you are ok with that, by all means, you can do it.

Comment: I don't need the exact angle instantly, I need just a boolean state; rotated or not.